# How to get keys and values of a JSON object in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, key-value

I'm making a table with emojis. I have a JSON object with about a hundred key-value pairs.
I'm trying to do that in *ngFor cycle with key-value pipe.

I need it to look like:

```
<td>+1</td>
<td>https://link</td>
```

But I get:

```
{
  "key": "0",
  "value": {
    "100": "https://link",
    "+1": "https://link",
    "-1": "https://link"
  }
}
```

My code:

```
//------------1------------
export class Emoji {
    [key:string]:string
}

//------------2-----------

export const EMOJIS: Emoji[] = [
  {
    "+1": "https://link",
    "-1": "https://link",
    "100": "https://link"
  }
];
```

```html
<!-- ------4------ -->
<h2>My Emojis</h2>
<table class="emojis">
  <tr *ngFor="let emoji of emojis | keyvalue">
    <td><span class="badge">{{emoji.key}}</span></td>
    <td>{{emoji.value}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `EMOJIS` is an array with a single item, that's why you're getting a key `0` (the one and only index) and a value -- the whole object with emojis.

Get rid of the array. Instead, just have an object:

```
export const EMOJIS = {
  "+1": "https://link",
  "-1": "https://link",
  "100": "https://link"
}
```

Now the `keyvalue` pipe will give you what you expect.

---

As for the typing issues, just use an interface -- you don't need a class.

```
interface Emoji { [key: string]: string } 
const emojis: Emoji = { '+1': 'link' }
```

Comment: Yeah. You're right. The problem is array. But if I get rid of it, my links are no longer assignable to Emoji class.

Comment: You don't need a class for it. Use an interface. I'll update my answer now.